# Quadratic form in Hilbert space associated with orthogonal projection operator

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, quadratic-forms

we are in Hilbert space $L^2 $ and we are given subspace of dimension $2K$
$$ V=Vect\{ g_k,\bar{g_k},1\le k\le K \}$$
$V$ is a sum of $K$ subspaces of dimension 2
$$ W_k=Vect \{g_k,\bar{g_k} \} $$
now we define 
$$ C(u,V):=\sum{}_{k=1}^{K} \|P_{W_k}u\|^2$$
where $P_{W_k}$ is orthogonal projection on $W_k$

how can i show that
$ C(u,V)$ restricted on vectors $u$ from $V$ a positive definite quadratic form asociated with operator $L=\sum_{k}P_{W_k}$ , and it also satisfies 
$$ A\|u\|^2 \le C(u,V) \le B\|u\|^2 $$
where $A$ and $B$ are max and min eigenvalue of that operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First show that $C^{\frac{1}{2}}(.,V)$ is a norm:

$C^{\frac{1}{2}}(\lambda u)=|\lambda|C(u,V)$ and

$\{\sum_k ||P_{W_k}(u+v)||^2\}^{\frac{1}{2}}\leq\{\sum_k ||P_{W_k}(u)||^2\}^{\frac{1}{2}}+\{\sum_k ||P_{W_k}(v)||^2\}^{\frac{1}{2}}$ if and only if

$\sum_k Re <P_{W_k}u,P_{W_k}v>\leq\{\sum_k ||P_{W_k}(u)||^2\}^{\frac{1}{2}}\{\sum_k ||P_{W_k}(v)||^2\}^{\frac{1}{2}} $, which follows from Cauchy Schwarz inequality.

Because $\sum_k||P_{W_k}(u\pm v)||^2=\sum_k ||P_{W_k}(u)||^2\pm Re<P_{W_k}u,P_{W_k}v>+||P_{W_k}v||^2$ it follows the parallelogramm identity:

$C(u+v,V)+C(u-v,V)=2(C(u,V)+C(v,V)$.

Hence C(.,V) is a quadratic form and because

$C(u,V)=0$ implies $P_{W_k}=0$ for all $k=1,...,K$ and since $u$ is in the span of these $W_k$ this implies $u=0$ and thus, that $C(.,V)$ is positive definite.

Now let $L=\sum_k P_{W_k}, u=\sum_l\lambda_l g_l+\mu_l\overline{g_l}$. Since the $P_{W_k}$ are orthogonal projections we have $P_{W_k}u=\lambda_kg_k+\mu_k\overline{g_k}$ and

$<Lu,u>=\sum_k <P_{W_k}u,\sum_l \lambda_lg_l+\mu_l\overline{g_l}>=\sum_k<P_{W_k}u,\lambda_kg_k+\mu_k\overline{g_k}>=\sum_k||P_{W_k}u||^2=C(u,V)$

and if $[A,B]$ contains the eigenvalues of $L$ we know by the min max theorem, that

$A\leq\frac{<Lu,u>}{<u,u>}\leq B$.

Comment: $<P_{W_k}u \ne \lambda_l g_l+\mu_l\overline{g_l}>$ because $g_l$ and $\overline{g_l}$  are not orthogonal but i get the idea. and about paralelogram identity, in my book i have that quadratic form satisfies paralelogram identity and defines norm ,and here you use it in reverse.  Can you recomand some book where i can find more ?

Comment: OK, I thought the subspaces $W_k$ are orthogonal, but however, may be You have to go a little bit more in detail at this point, well if a norm $||.||$ obeys the paralellogram identity, then  $<x,y>:=\frac{1}{4}(||x+y||^2-||x-y||^2+i||x+iy||^2-i||x-iy||^2)$ is the associated inner product (over $\mathbb{R}$ just $\frac{1}{4}(||x+y||^2-||x-y||^2)$, it´s usually called polarization formula and can be found in most books on functional analysis, not in those i´ve here though

Comment: oh, i know that (Jordan - Neumann theorem), so we can make inner product form $C(\cdot,V)$  that inner product makes norm $C(\cdot,V)^(1/2)$ and that same inner product makes (because it's inner product) quadratic form as $<x,x>$  , right ?

Comment: Right!I found a book: Kosaku Yosidas "Functional Analysis" I.5."pre-Hilbert spaces", in general a very good book